# adding variable values in json file using push function

Tags: javascript, json

I have a json file and two variables, i want to store the variables values in the json file using push function in json. my code is

```
  var x=xmen;
var z=xmen website
var jsonObj = {
"items":
[
    {
        "title":"some title",
        "url":"some url"
    }    
]
};
```

I want my resulting json file to be

```
var jsonObj = {
"items":
[
    {
        "title":"some title",
        "url":"some url"
    }  
{
        "title":"xmen",
        "url":"xmen website"
    }    
]
};
```

I dont want to use arrays just while pushing the value using

```
jsonObj.items.push
```

i want to call the variable and assign like example

```
jsonObj.items.push({"title":+x+,"url":+url+}); //just to explain, its not the original function.
```

Comment: I don't think you can manipulate JSON objects. You will have to parse it and treat `items` as an array.

Comment: @Ayman Safadi : i have parsed it and im applying push function, but my problem is that i want to assign variable value to a key in json file. my last piece of code explains my problem. can u help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `push` is your problem. It's your object syntax that's messed up.

Instead of

```
{"title":+x+,"url":+url+}
```

Try this instead:

```
// Assuming that "x" and "url" are valid variables
{"title":x,"url":url}
```

Here's a quick demo of everything working: http://jsbin.com/zicofoye/1/edit

```
jsonObj.items.push({
    "title":"avengers",
    "url":"avengers website"
});
```

Comment: the problem is that im getting values from html and storing it in x and z. now i have to insert values of x and z in json file using push function. im storing it in variable using  k={"title":x,"url":z}  and applying jsonObj.items.push(k);. but the values are not getting inserted in jsonobj

Comment: OK... I have a feeling that you left out a critical piece of your problem. Sounds like your problem has nothing to do with JSON or arrays; that part obviously works. Please update your question with the code showing how you're setting `x` and `z`. Also, could you please be more clear as to what the problem is? What' you're trying to do? What's happening instead? (i.e. Error messages?)